# Find in Sublime Text 2: how to make sublime text search for double quotes when I use find with quote and vise versa

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a JavaScrip document that is very long. I need to find strings that come before or after specific pattern, but I don't know if author of document used single quote (`'`) or double quote (`"`) for strings. So I have to repeat my search every time.

Can I make Sublime Text ignore double or single quote and search for all matching patterns?

Comment: Why don't you use regex for that?

Comment: Doing search twice is faster than write a regex for me.

Answer (score 4):

Turn on Regular Expressions with `Alt+R`, then type the following into the search field:

```
["'](String To Find)["']
```

The brackets surrounding your `String To Find` will allow you to reference the matched string with `\1`

Comment: How can I implement this regex in a Sublime Plug-in?

Comment: I haven't created a plugin before but this might help: [Nettuts: How to Create a Sublime Text 2 Plugin](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/)